# Google Places returns the street address in formatted_address but not in address_components

Tags: javascript, google-places-api, google-places

For certain places, Google Places is returning the full address of the place in the `formatted_address` field. However, the street address component is not present in `address_components`.

From the [Google Places API docs](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details):

> The formatted address is logically composed of one or more address
>   components.

And then later on:

> Do not parse the formatted address programmatically. Instead you
>   should use the individual address components, which the API response
>   includes in addition to the formatted address field.

How are we supposed to programmatically retrieve to the street address if it isn't included in `address_components`?

As an example, I'm seeing this issue with a [San Diego DMV location](https://www.google.com/maps/place/DMV+MOBILE+VEHICLE+VERIFICATION+%26+REGISTRATION/@32.8184026,-117.1783031,19z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x80dc00745c553a9f:0x58bff24c3f27db80!8m2!3d32.8184026!4d-117.1777559). The street address (5858 Mt Alifan 204) is not showing up in the `address_components`, but it is showing up in the `formatted_address`:

```
{
   ...
   "result" : {
      "address_components" : [
         {
            "long_name" : "San Diego",
            "short_name" : "San Diego",
            "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "Clairemont",
            "short_name" : "Clairemont",
            "types" : [ "neighborhood", "political" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "San Diego County",
            "short_name" : "San Diego County",
            "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "California",
            "short_name" : "CA",
            "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "United States",
            "short_name" : "US",
            "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "92117",
            "short_name" : "92117",
            "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "4940",
            "short_name" : "4940",
            "types" : [ "postal_code_suffix" ]
         }
      ],
      ...
      "formatted_address" : "5858 Mt Alifan 204, San Diego, CA 92117, USA",
      ...
}
```